# Recursive svn propset

Tags: svn

I'm trying to recursively add properties to all files with a wildcard.

File structure as below

```
D:>dir *.bob /s/b
D:\Source\key-test\test.bob
D:\Source\key-test\test2.bob
D:\Source\key-test\sub\test3.bob
```

properties so far (none)

```
D:>svn propget svn:keywords -R *.bob
```

try a recursive set (note test3.bob is missing)

```
D:>svn propset svn:keywords "Author HeadURL Id Revision" -R *.bob
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'test.bob'
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'test2.bob'
```

change to sub and make sure we can set the prop (ok)

```
D:>cd sub
D:>svn propset svn:keywords "Author HeadURL Id Revision" -R *.bob
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'test3.bob'
```

Anyone know what's up with **-R**, I've also tried **--recursive**?

Cheers,

adam

```
D:>svn --version
svn, version 1.6.6 (SlikSvn:tag/1.6.6@40358) WIN32
   compiled Nov  3 2009, 15:31:43
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that there is ambiguity over the docs for what -R does (or doesn't do) as pointed out by Gonzalo I've used this batch file instead of trying to get svn to do what I want

```
D:>type applyProps.cmd
@echo off
for /r . %%X in (*.bob) do (
svn propset svn:keywords "Author Id HeadURL Revision" "%%X"
)
```

Answer (score 19):

Actually -R is recursive. For example:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style 'LF' -R *
```

This will work on all subfolders as well. However:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style 'LF' -R *.php
```

...will only work on php files within the current folder, regardless of the -R. Adding:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style 'LF' -R */*.php
```

Will work on subfolders one level down. Adding extra /-s will go another level and so on...

I'm really not sure how to specify (or if it is even possible to do so) that it should be filtered based on file name AND recursive. Regardless, experimenting can't hurt, since the modifications are local and can always be thrown away by reverting...

Answer (score 11):

From `svn help propset`:

> The svn:keywords, svn:executable,
>   svn:eol-style, svn:mime-type and
>   svn:needs-lock properties cannot be
>   set on a directory.  A non-recursive
>   attempt will fail, and a recursive
>   attempt will set the property   only
>   on the file children of the directory.

Comment: Are you saying that despite the help listing -R as a valid option, the above paragraph _a recursive attempt will set the property only on the file children of the directory_ overrides this and -R is therefore or not valid?

Comment: Yes, that's what I gather from the help. In *nix you could use `find . -name \*.bob | xargs svn propset ....` to achieve what you want, but no idea how to do that on windows without cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If your working directory is under UNIX, you can also try this command. It works for me:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Id" `du -a | cut -f 2 | grep -v "\.svn" | grep "\.bob$" | sed "s/ /[[:space:]]/g"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just recursively changed properties on .xml files from application/xml to text/xml and was trying to see if there was a better way to do it. I couldn't find one, but stumbled across this question. Though it's old, this is the most succinct way I found:

```
find /<root_dir> -print | grep '.<extension>' | xargin svn propset svn:<property> <new_ property_value> $@
```

`find -print` recursively lists all files in all sub directories of `<root_dir>` with their full path starting with `<root_dir>`

`grep '.<extension>'` receives the piped output from `find` as input and filters it based on the extension you're looking for

`xargin` allows you to execute a command that may not work smoothly with piped input in stdin, which can be referenced with `$@`

For example, my exact command was

```
find /config -print | grep '.xml' | xargin svn propset svn:mime-type text/xml $@
```

Note `<root_dir>` must be an immediate sub-directory of your present working directory